# WPF RowDefinition Weirdness

Tags: wpf, xaml, snoop

I have an app I'm trying to debug, and I'm looking at various settings at runtime via snoop.

The problem I'm having is this:

There is a grid, with a height of 50.4 . It has 3 RowDefinitions each with a height of 1 star (*). Therefore one would assume that each RowDefinition will have an actual height of 50.4/3 (16.8). However, I can see that the first 2 RowDefinitions have an ActualHeight of 25.2 and the third has an ActualHeight of 0. All three still have a Height of 1 star.

How is this possible ? I just can see how you can achieve this situation. You cant change the ActualHeight grammatically as its read-only. The heights must have been set in the Grid's Arrange pass.

Does anyone know of any set of circumstances that would produce this scenario.

Comment: Can you provide a small but complete sample project to reproduce that behavior?

Comment: Im afraid not, there is a problem with this very complex application. Something is creating this scenario, which I thought was not possible. Im looking for any ideas about how this could happen, which would help me track down the cause

Comment: I am certain that you will gain a lot of insights in trying to create such a minimal sample. You would start with your complex application and remove more and more code. At some point you remove some code and the problem doesn't happen anymore. You now know what the offending piece of code is...

Comment: Maybe someone changes row`s Height from code-behind?

Comment: I may have expressed my wish for an answer a little clumsily. I could spend days de-constructing the application, and Im sure I'll get a Eureka moment at some point. The reason I posted the question here is to see if anyone just 'knows' a scenario that can produce this situation. If no-one answers, then I have a lot more work to do :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer - I don't know if its a WPF bug, or that I haven't read the documentation properly

```
<Border Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="123" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="123" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="123" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="123" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox Text="123" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        <TextBox Text="123" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

If you look at the code, you will see that there are 3 star(*) sized rows, which should ALL have equal share of the grid's height, regardless of their contents.

However, when you collapse ALL of the contents assigned to that row, the row itself ALSO collapses. (if you snoop it it has a height of *, but an ActualHeight of 0)

Does anyone consider this normal behavior ? Ive never heard of this in all of my WPF development over the last 5 years

Comment: Does your `Border` have a defined height, or does it also collapse (or contract) it's height when the row collapses?

Comment: Nothing has a defined height, so the border will automatically size to its content. You do not need the border for this code to behave like this, I put the border there so that the red background shows you that the grid has a collapsed row

Comment: Right, what I was getting at was whether there was a defined height or not.  If there is no defined height then this is the behavior I would expect.  Put the grid into a DockPanel, or give it a fixed height, and you will get the behavior you expect.  This has to do with the grid trying to measure it's height, and since the row has nothing to measure, the row ends up with a 0 height, and reduces the overall grid height.

Comment: OK, I think you've hit the nail on the head. Basically if there is no fixed size to a grid, then any row that has no contents assigned (or collapsed contents) and is star sized, will basically disappear as if it wasn't in the XAML in the first place. I guess the same behaviour will be evident with columns. Thanks for that - its not every day you learn something new that is so fundamental :)